# Limiting ":hover" area of "div"

Tags: css

I've created a popup box that shows when hovered over an image. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="infoimg" style="float: left;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/W1FxGnH.png" alt="Lorem ipsum" width="62" height="61">
<div class="infobox"><span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <ul style="padding-top: 15px;padding-left:5px; margin-left: 5px;list-style-type: disc;">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      <li>Consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Sed maximus magna vel facilisis vulputate.</li>
      <li>Mauris sit amet elit sit amet ipsum.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.infobox {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 72px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.infoimg:hover div.infobox {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 72px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

However, since I'm using "opacity: 0" for the "infobox" div instead of using "display: none" (to create a fade-in/out effect), the infobox is technically still there. This is where my issue comes in, when the mouse hovers over the invisible "infobox" area, the hovering effect takes place. What I wanted was to initiate the hovering effect only when the mouse pointer is over the "infoimg" div. I've tried applying the following code to try to limit the area but it did not work:

```
.infoimg {
  width: 62px;
  height: 61px;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle link for a live demonstration of what my issue is: https://jsfiddle.net/x9h5rqdw/

As you can see, when the mouse is over the empty area (infobox) next to "infoimg", the hover effect gets initiated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very simple.
You need to add `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible;`

CSS:

```
.infobox {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 72px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
  /* here */
  visibility: hidden;
}

.infoimg:hover div.infobox {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 72px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
  /* here */
  visibility: visible;
}

.infoimg {
  width: 62px;
  height: 61px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

`pointer-events: none;` is the simplest way but it's not cross browser:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/x9h5rqdw/4/

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer.  It points out that `pointer-events` is a solution but highlights its drawbacks whilst also providing a cross browser solution.

Comment: Thank you! Changed the code to this & marked as best answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `pointer-events: none` on `.infobox` to fix that behaviour.

> The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events. When this property is unspecified, the same characteristics of the visiblePainted value apply to SVG content.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events